# Array.prototype.sort method changes array value as well as variable value of that array

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, typescript

`Array.prototype.sort()` method changes the array, so the value of the variable that refers to it is changed as well. It looks horrible to me, and I am unable to access the original array afterwards.

For example:

```
function keepOriginalArray([...arr]){

    let storeWithoutSorting = arr; // I want original copy of array in variable.

    arr.sort()

    return storeWithoutSorting // gives result ['a','b'] . Variable's value was changed after calling sort method. 

}

keepOriginalArray(['b', 'a'])
```

I am curious to know how does it work and how can I store a copy of the original array in a variable in this situation?

Comment: You are making a copy of the argument by destructuring it with `keepOriginalArray([...arr])` . Your function won't change the array passed into the function. It's not clear why you are creating *another* copy inside the function.

Comment: @MarkMeyer IMO you should consider it posting as answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Sort` mutates original array so you need to create a copy of array. here i am using `...` spread syntax to create a shallow copy of original array

```js
function keepOriginalArray(arr){
    let storeWithoutSorting = [...arr];
    arr.sort()
    return storeWithoutSorting 
}

console.log(keepOriginalArray(['b', 'a']))
```

Answer (score 2):

Array is reference type. When you are storing arr value to storeWithoutSorting , you are actually storing its reference. Thats why both are getting sorted when you are performing the sort.
To create a copy of an array, you can use spread operator:

```
 let storeWithoutSorting = [...arr]
```

It will create a new array with new reference. Hence it won't be manipulated when you perform sort on arr.